# Error Occurred While Updating Some of the Page

Tags: xpages

I have a combobox that performs a partial refresh of a hidden table.  I'm trying to show the table once any value is selected other than the default value.  I am using a hidden edit field that is bound to a scope variable to control the table rendering or not.  I believe the problem I am having is my code is doing the partial refresh first before the scope variable is set ( see code below onComplete...).  However, I am unsure how to set the scope variable first before the refresh occurs.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
<xp:comboBox id="vendorAppAdvSkills1">
    <xp:selectItem itemLabel="-Select a Category-"
        itemValue="" id="selectItem1">
    </xp:selectItem>
    <xp:selectItems id="selectItems1">
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:getComponent( "vendorAppSkills1" ).getValue();}]]></xp:this.value>
    </xp:selectItems>
    <xp:eventHandler event="onblur" submit="false"
        id="eventHandler1">
        <xp:this.script><![CDATA[
XSP.partialRefreshPost("#{id:tblAdvertising}", 
{ 
    //  Added showAdvertising code to hide the advertising table until the user selects their free category!
    onComplete: function() 
    { 
        //  Fetch a handle to the first category field
        var freeCategory = dojo.byId('#{id:vendorAppAdvSkills1}');
        var showAdvertising = document.getElementById('#{id:showAdvertising}');
        //  If it's blank, force the cursor off the field to fire the onBlur Event
        if( freeCategory.value == "" || freeCategory.value == null )
        {
            if($('body').scrollTop()>0)
            {
                $('body').scrollTop(0);         //Chrome,Safari
            }
            else
            {
                if($('html').scrollTop()>0)
                {    //IE, FF
                    $('html').scrollTop(0);
                }
            } 
            showAdvertising.value = false;
            //  Notify the user this is required
            alert( "Please Select Your FREE Category Listing!" );
            //  Place the cursor back in the first category field again
            freeCategory.focus();
        }
        else
            showAdvertising.value = true;
    }
} );]]></xp:this.script>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:comboBox>
```

NEW CODE ADDED HERE

```
<xp:comboBox id="vendorAppAdvSkills1">
<xp:selectItem itemLabel="-Select a Category-"
    itemValue="" id="selectItem1">
</xp:selectItem>
<xp:selectItems id="selectItems1">
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:getComponent( "vendorAppSkills1" ).getValue();}]]></xp:this.value>
</xp:selectItems>
<xp:eventHandler event="onblur" submit="true" refreshMode="partial" refreshId="tblAdvertising"
    onComplete="alert( 'ssjs code done' )">
    <xp:this.script><![CDATA[#{javascript:
    var vendorAppSkills = getComponent( "vendorAppSkills1" ).getValue(); 
    print( "vendorAppSkills: " + vendorAppSkills ); 
    print( "typeof vendorAppSkills: " + typeof vendorAppSkills ); 
    if( typeof vendorAppSkills == "java.util.Vector" )
    {
        if( vendorAppSkills.contains( "-Select a Category-" ) )
            viewScope.put( "showAdvertising", false );
    }
    else
    {
        if( typeof( vendorAppSkills == "String" ) )
            if( vendorAppSkills.equalsIgnoreCase( "-Select a Category-" ) )
                viewScope.put( "showAdvertising", false );
            else
                viewScope.put( "showAdvertising", true );
    }
    }]]></xp:this.script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of doing the partial refresh with `XSP.partialRefreshPost` use the `refreshId` parameter of the event handler, set your scope variable, then your onComplete code will run after the scoped variable has been assigned a value:

```
    <xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">

        <xp:this.afterPageLoad><![CDATA[#{javascript:viewScope.myVar = "initial value";}]]></xp:this.afterPageLoad>
        <xp:comboBox id="comboBox1">
            <xp:selectItem itemLabel="val 1" itemValue="val1"></xp:selectItem>
            <xp:selectItem itemLabel="val 2" itemValue="val2"></xp:selectItem>
            <xp:eventHandler event="onchange" submit="true" refreshMode="partial"
              refreshId='#{javascript:(viewScope.myVar == "someValue") ? "idToUpdate" : ""}'
              onComplete="alert('ssjs code done');">
                <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:viewScope.myVar = "someValue";}]]></xp:this.action>
            </xp:eventHandler>
        </xp:comboBox>

        <xp:panel id="idToUpdate">
            <xp:this.rendered><![CDATA[#{javascript:(viewScope.myVar == "someValue")}]]></xp:this.rendered>
            table data
        </xp:panel>
    </xp:view>
```

Comment: I tried implementing what you said and still get the same error :(

Take a look at my new code and let me know if yous see something wrong.

Comment: I also realized my print statements are executing only on the load not the refresh

Comment: All of your server side code should be in `<xp:this.action>` tag not `<xp:this.script>`. Try using the syntax in the my example... `<xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript: `

Comment: Also since you are hiding the table by default you need to compute the refreshId property... see my updated answer

Comment: Dude, you rock!  That solved my problem!  Thank you so much.